Format as iterables while writing to files using python
I am writing a simple data file using:
f = open(filename,'w')

for i in range(len(xarr)):
   f.write("%16.8e\t%16.8e\t%16.8e\n" %(xarr[i], y1[i], y2[i]))
f.close()

I want to put this into a function and use it to write many files. The number of arrays I am writing is different each time (y1,y2,.....etc.).
How can I mention the format as an iterable so that it changes according to the number of arrays I need to write?
Thank you.

f.write(*\t".join(["%18.8e"]*len(xarr)).format(*xarr). Sorry is that is slightly off as I'm on my phone.

You don't need a single format string. Use zip() to pivot the list of lists, and then use a generator to apply the format string to all the items in the corresponding positions in each list.
def write_arrays(filename, arrays):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        for items in zip(*arrays):
            f.write("\t".join("%16.8e".format(item) for item in items))
            f.write("\n")

